# Programmatically creating the new iOS15 FaceTime Links

Tags: ios, swift, facetime, ios15

I've been trying to figure out if in iOS15, there will be a way to create a FaceTime link through our own apps, so that the app can be used as a sort of booking tool.

I've searched online and the closest thing I found was the old URL scheme that looks like this:

```
facetime://user@example.com
```

But will we be able to create custom identifiers that can be used with the new FaceTime Links?